# Onclick is not working in firefox or safari

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following button to insert into database as follows:

```
<button id="valida" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onclick="inserir_senha();">Alterar</button> 

function inserir_senha()
{  
var dadosajax = {
    'senhaatual' : $("#senhaatual").val(),
    'senhanova' : $("#senhanova").val(),
    'senhaconfir' : $("#senhaconfir").val()
    
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'alterarsenha.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: dadosajax,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data)
    {
        if (data.result){                            
            $(".success_messages").removeClass('hide'); 
        }else{
            Swal.fire('Alerta!', data.message,'warning');
        }
    }
});    
}
```

Everything works fine on google chrome, but on safari and firefox it doesn't work and doesn't work. can help

Comment: Onclick works of course, problem is elsewhere. Check console for errors.

Comment: "it doesn't work and doesn't work" are two of the worst problem reports I've heard :). Please enlighten us on what they mean. What doesn't happen that you think should happen? What happens that you think shouldn't? How have you tried debugging the code to see what is happening in the offending browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace type="submit" with type="button" it should work.